# Error cuando ejecuto uvicorn con FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

buenas tardes, soy nuevito en python y mas nuevo aun en fastapi (lo poco que habia hecho era con django), resulta que cuando quiero iniciar uvicorn (está chequeado que está instalado) me tira el siguiente error y no estoy encontrando por ningun lado la solución, el error es el siguiente       uvicorn: The term 'uvicorn' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]